# Flutter Riverpod StateProvider having slow rebuild of widget when using watch

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm using Riverpod with StateProvider for my app.

The home page will change based on tabs clicked.
When i click the ListTile tab to trigger the ref.read, it rebuild super fast:
But when i click the leading IconButton in Appbar which trigger `ref.read(countProvider.notifier).state = 0;` it takes me fews seconds to reload the back to 0. How do i fix this?
Full code:
layout.dart:

```
Set<Widget> _pages = {
  const HomeUI(),
  const FAQ(),
  const Setting(),
};

class Layout extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const Layout({super.key});

  @override
  LayoutState createState() => LayoutState();
}

class LayoutState extends ConsumerState<Layout> {

  bool isHome = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tab = ref.watch(countProvider);
    if (tab != 0) {
      isHome = false;
    } else {
      isHome = true;
    }
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const Sidebar(),
      appBar: isHome
          ? AppBar(
              leading: Builder(builder: (context) {
                return IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.bars),
                  color: CustomColors.mainText,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                  },
                );
              }),
              actions: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.magnifyingGlass),
                    color: CustomColors.mainText,
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            )
          : null,
      backgroundColor: CustomColors.background,
      body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        _pages.elementAt(tab),
        const MiniPlayer(),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

faq_screen.dart

```
class FAQ extends StatelessWidget {
  const FAQ({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(
      builder: (context, ref, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () {
                ref.read(countProvider.notifier).state = 0;
              },
            ),
            title: const Text('FAQ'),
          ),
          body: const Center(
            child: Text('FAQ'),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

sidebar.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

import '../utilities/color.dart';
import '../utilities/provider.dart';

class Sidebar extends StatelessWidget {
  const Sidebar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      backgroundColor: CustomColors.background,
      child: Consumer(
        builder: (context, ref, child) => ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: const Text("Wolhaiksong",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'Gilroy',
                      fontWeight: CustomColors.semiBold)),
              accountEmail: const Text("deptraicojsai@gmail.com",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'Gilroy',
                      fontWeight: CustomColors.regular)),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/user.jpg'),
                ),
              ),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/wallpaper.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.lightbulb,
                color: CustomColors.gray,
              ),
              title: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Text('FAQs',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: CustomColors.mainText,
                      fontWeight: CustomColors.semiBold,
                      fontFamily: 'Gilroy',
                    )),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                ref.read(countProvider.notifier).state = 1;
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.gear,
                color: CustomColors.gray,
              ),
              title: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Text('Settings',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: CustomColors.mainText,
                      fontWeight: CustomColors.semiBold,
                      fontFamily: 'Gilroy',
                    )),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                ref.read(countProvider.notifier).state = 2;
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

provider.dart

```
final countProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) {
  return 0;
});
```

Comment: Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: Could you explain more about why shouldn't those be used?

Comment: It's a strong recommendation from Remi (riverpod author).   The deprecated providers encourage mutation code in the view layer, not in the model layer, so it leads to bad layering.  Modern providers require mutations to be encapsulated in the notifier by publishing an API that the view layer can use.

Comment: I understand now, can you have a look at my code below and offer me a solution? I haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you basically want to reset your provider to 0, instead of setting the value directly, you can try this:

```dart
ref.refresh(countProvider);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry guys, turns out the problem is not Riverpod but the async function i used to extract dominant color from the image.

```
static Future<Color> generatePaletteColor(url) async {
    final PaletteGenerator paletteGenerator =
        await PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider(
        AssetImage(url),
    );
    return paletteGenerator.paletteColors[0].color;
}
```

And I use it in initState so it runs everytime countProvider change

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    CustomColors.generatePaletteColor(widget.song.artWork).then((value) {
        if (mounted) {
            setState(() {
                glowColor = value;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Is there anyway to move the async function outside of this or prevent `initState` from rerun everytime rebuilt?